# Issue With DAO 3.6 on VB6 database

Tags: database, vb6, dao

I am currently in the process of trying to launch a database that has a VB6 front end connected to an access 2000 database. On certain computers we are experiencing a problem where the data being pulled from the database does not show up or does not show up correctly.

The computers that work seem to have the same dao360.dll date modified in both the system 32 and microsoftshared/dao while the one that are not working do not have the same date modified.

Is this whats causing the error? How can I correct this? Or is it something else that is happening?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the systems that don't work (correctly)?

Comment: There are no error's actually showing up when the program runs. It is a scheduling program that displays data, on the computer that displays it lists the programs correctly, while on the ones that don't nothing displays.

Comment: Can you be more specific on where it's not showing up? If it's not showing up in your code, have you tried debugging to see what the code is actually getting back?

Comment: Could you be seeing the results of Windows Virtualisation for non admin apps writing to a protected area getting their own provate copy?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be two copies of the DLL on the system.  It sounds like a poorly designed install of some application had been previously done on these systems.  There is no telling what the full extent of this has been.

Packaging as an isolated application can insulate your programs from these kinds of bad installs that create DLL Hell.  Sadly MDAC/DAC and related components are very difficult to isolate.

This is another reason to have moved to ADO back in 1998, if not in the time since then.  While you can't isolate the ADO-related parts of MDAC/DAC any more than you can DAO, those libraries are now shipped as part of Windows.  You don't need to deploy them and they are protected from bad installers by the increasingly better system file protection mechanisms in Windows.

---

However providing specific assistance will probably require a more specific and detailed description of what is going on than "does not show up or show up corectly."

I'd create a minimal test case using DAO to begin exploring where (and what) the problems really are.  To begin with perhaps just a simple query displaying the returned rowset without data binding.

Comment: To be honest I'm skeptical that it has anything to do with the .dll files anymore. I'll post some code when I get the chance.

Comment: Well that's good news... I guess. Doesn't fix it but you're getting closer.

Comment: That being said...I'm going to wipe the hard drive and start again to see if that doesn't fix the issue, since the computers are there basically to run this system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing the latest version of MDAC and Jet.  While Jet used to be a part of the MDAC, I'm pretty sure they dropped it into its own installl/update/service pack at this point.  Perhaps start here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114